# unattened authentication using Azure Active Directory- UserCredential not accepting username and password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was following the example given below to accomplish unattended authentication to azure management apis with azure active directory.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/11/24/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory/

In the latest Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.10.305231913 UserCredential Class does not accept user and password. In the older version say v2.18.0.0 UserCredential class does accept username and password. Not sure in which version this was deprecated.

How do I accomplish this in the latest version. Most of the articles I have come across seem to refer older one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UserPasswordCredential` instead of `UserCredential` with new version ADAL 3.0

`UserPasswordCredential` is inherited from `UserCredential` which accepts both username and password.